# Can you call ko.applyBindings to bind a partial view?

Tags: ajax, html, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS and have a main view and view model. I want a dialog (the jQuery UI one) to popup with another view which a separate child view model to be bound to.

The HTML for the dialog content is retrieved using AJAX so I want to be able to call `ko.applyBindings` once the request has completed, and I want to bind the child view model to just the portion of the HTML loaded via ajax inside the dialog div.

Is this actually possible or do I need to load ALL my views and view models when the page initially loads and then call `ko.applyBindings` once?

Answer (score 431, accepted):

`ko.applyBindings` accepts a second parameter that is a DOM element to use as the root.

This would let you do something like:

```html
<div id="one">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>

<div id="two">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewModelA = {
     name: ko.observable("Bob")
  };

  var viewModelB = {
     name: ko.observable("Ted")
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById("one"));
  ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById("two"));
</script>
```

So, you can use this technique to bind a viewModel to the dynamic content that you load into your dialog.  Overall, you just want to be careful not to call `applyBindings` multiple times on the same elements, as you will get multiple event handlers attached.

Comment: If you also want to remove bindings at some point down the road you can call either `ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("one")` to clean things up or `ko.removeNode(document.getElementById("one")` to clean things up and remove the node from the DOM.

Comment: Just a note that `cleanNode` and `removeNode` will not remove event handlers, so use some caution.  In some cases, it is preferable to use the `template` or `with` binding on those areas, so you have new elements rendered.

Comment: How would you go about cleaning things up completely?  There ought to be a way to detach/unbind event handlers created by KO...

Comment: It is currently something that is lacking in KO. We do not specifically intend for people to "rebind" sections.  However, KO does attach events using jQuery, if it is referenced, so you can do `$(element).unbind();` to remove all handlers.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this? 

`$(element).find("*").each(function () {
            $(this).unbind();
        });`

Comment: Where are these functions (applyBindings, cleanNode, removeNode) documented?  I can't find their function signatures on knockoutjs.com.

Comment: Would be nice if this was somewhere easily locatable within the documentation. I didn't even see a mention of it.

Comment: applyBindings 2nd parameter is mentioned in documentation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Anyone interested in this question may find this related question and answer interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186505/including-script-specific-to-an-asp-net-mvc4-view-or-partial-view/21290579#21290579

Answer (score 61):

While Niemeyer's answer is a more correct answer to the question, you *could* also do the following:

```html
<div>
  <input data-bind="value: VMA.name" />
</div>

<div>
  <input data-bind="value: VMB.name" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewModels = {
     VMA: {name: ko.observable("Bob")},
     VMB: {name: ko.observable("Ted")}
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModels);
</script>
```

This means you don't have to specify the DOM element, and you can even bind multiple models to the same element, like this:

```html
<div>
  <input data-bind="value: VMA.name() + ' and ' + VMB.name()" />
</div>
```

Comment: you can also use "with" to allocate regions of the page to individual models - data-bind="with:VMA"

Comment: @flamingpenguin: Yes, but `with` doesn't come cheap, see: [link](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html)

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to bind a custom model to an element at runtime. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZiglioNZ/tzD4T/457/

The interesting bit is that I apply the data-bind attribute to an element I didn't define:

```
    var handle = slider.slider().find(".ui-slider-handle").first();
    $(handle).attr("data-bind", "tooltip: viewModel.value");
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel.value, $(handle)[0]);
```

Comment: having trouble with ko 2.3, the code above is in a customer handler that is called when I apply the global ko.applyBindings(). So now I get the error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.". I'm still trying to figure out why I get the error. Can't we apply a binding to the same variable multiple times, each to different elements?

Comment: Here's the version with ko 2.3 that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZiglioNZ/tzD4T/458/

Comment: Adding a call to ko.cleanNode() before calling applyBinding to the partial view doesn't seem to help: http://jsfiddle.net/ZiglioNZ/tzD4T/459/

Comment: Solved: I didn't even need to call applyBindings!

Comment: ive just edited the knockoutjs source code and commented the part where the function twrows "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.", now all works ok... i know this is a dirty solution but im new to the library so i dont know how to not to apply it multiple times for  my problem.

Comment: @Geomorillo, not sure about your case, but in my one, I only needed to apply the attribute "data-bind", no need to call ok.applyBindings() again, even if only on a partial view

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `with` binding, as well as `controlsDescendantBindings` http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

Comment: it looks complicated. Is ko 3.0 going to be any simpler?