# Add bindings after calling ko.applyBindings

Tags: binding, knockout.js

In KnockoutJS, is there any way to add bindings after calling `ko.applyBindings`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS: ko.applyBindings to partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/knockoutjs-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the answer to my question is the same as this one: [Can you call ko.applyBindings to bind a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7342814/660664)

ko.applyBindings accepts a second parameter, limiting the scope of binding to a specific element within the DOM. So as long as we know where the new bindings are located in the DOM, we can apply them separately afterwards.

Comment: And if we do not know? e.g. I load compontents asnyc using AMD.