# knockoutjs : dynamic binding with svg element

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, knockout.js, d3.js

`<svg></svg>`> I am creating new svg element and set binding dynamically for them. But i dont know why it is not working. I am new to knockoutjs so kindly let me know where is the actual problem. Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/12/) for the problem (). and let me know if any clearification needed. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `ko.applyBindings` again for the newly injected element. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281875/knockout-js-update-bindings) for more information.

Comment: i am pretty new in knockoutjs. can you correct it in my given jsFiddle link ? thanks again .