# Knockout-Kendo Chart - remove and add series

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-kendo

My project is MVC 5, I am using the following to generate a chart with multiple series:

**HTML:**

```
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
<button data-bind="click: removeItem">Remove</button>
 <div data-bind="kendoChart2: { title: { text: 'Graph Sample' }, 
series: seriesConfig,tooltip: {visible: true,template: '#= series.name #: #= value #'} , seriesDefaults: {
                        type: 'line',style: 'smooth'}}"> </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var MainViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.Systolic = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.Diastolic = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.HeartRate= ko.observableArray([]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Charts/GetChart',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                //Diastolic
                if (result && result.Systolic.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.Systolic.length; i++) {
                        self.Systolic.push(result.Systolic[i].Systolic);
                    }
                };
               ....
            },
            error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
             }});

    this.seriesConfig = ko.observableArray([
                {name: "Systolic", data: this.Systolic()},
                {name: "Diastolic",data: this.Diastolic()}]);
    this.addItem = function() {
    this.seriesConfig.push({ name: "Heart Rate", data: this.HeartRate() });
                };
     this.removeItem = function() {
     this.seriesConfig.remove({ name: "Diastolic", data: this.Diastolic() });
        };
        }.bind(this);
      ko.kendo.bindingFactory.createBinding(
{
    name: "kendoChart",
    bindingName: "kendoChart2",
    watch: {
      data: function(value) {
          ko.kendo.setDataSource(this, value);
      },
      series: function(value) {
           this._sourceSeries = value;
           this.refresh();
           this.redraw();}            
    }
});
        window.viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

The chart works great, however can't add or remove series?

**Note:**
the addItem works, I get the value of the new series:

```
series: function (value) {
        alert(value[2].name);
        this.seriesConfig = value;
        this.refresh();
        this.redraw();
      }
```

I also tried load all series then use the following hide a series:

```
$("#kendoChart").getKendoChart().options.series[1].visible = false;
$("#kendoChart").getKendoChart().redraw();
```

Does not work, I think the chart name does not register.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with knockout-kendo, just with knockout in general, so if fixing obvious problem as described below will not work, you might need to [refresh bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281875/knockout-js-update-bindings). Looking at [this example](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/dataviz/Chart.html) however this is not needed, so most likely you got caught by a simple fact that array's remove performs simple `==` comparison and it fails to find equal object in the array.

Here is a simplified example (although you might know it already, but just in case):

```
var a="abc";
var b="abc";
var aa = [1,2,3,"a","b","c"];
var data1 = {name: a, data: aa};
var data2 = {name: b, data: aa};
```

now, comparison `a==b` returns `true` and clearly `data` slots are the same, however `data1==data2` is `false`. That is because it's a different object.

So in your example in removeItem you create and pass a new object to remove, not the one in the array, so `==` comparison fails and nothing is removed as that newly created object isn't in your observable array.

I suggest comparing the name only similar to `item.age < 18` comparison from knockout.js documentation on [observable arrays](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

```
this.seriesConfig.remove( function (item) { return item.name == "Diastolic"; } )
```

I believe, this should do the trick.