# KnockoutJs app with tabbed User Interface: What is best practice?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, tabbed-interface

I'm constructing a single page KnockoutJs app with multi-tab functionality.

Thus far, I have tried out jQuery UI's tab functionality with the basic idea I had in mind.

Here's a my example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/curiousdev/nQhn9/)

using this jQuery UI function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

How would you build out tabs in a Knockoutjs app? Are there best practices?

Does this seem like a good direction? or are there any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Depending on the requirements, you should probably consider having a separate viewmodel for each tab, and again if it fits with the requirements have each tab populated with an ajax call.

Comment: Or are you looking to create tabs dynamically, based on the viewmodel data?

Comment: Looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/UCGRZ/

Comment: @beon The main answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293761/knockoutjs-multiple-view-models-in-a-single-view) seems reasonable for having multiple view models. I'm not looking to create the tabs dynamically

Comment: @Tyrsius I not sure if understand your example. It seems the same as my implementation

Comment: @Curiosdev Sorry that was supposed to be a question. Is this like what you are looking for?

Comment: @beon this is the example I came up with: ttp://jsfiddle.net/curiousdev/REnaE/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at [PagerJS](http://pagerjs.com/).

> **PagerJS** is a JavaScript library based on KnockoutJS and jQuery that provides the possibility of creating single page applications in a declarative fashion - nesting subpages inside subpages where each subpage can be developed standalone but still communicate between each other.

I have a project which is somewhat completed that is using PagerJS for a single page application and it might be of some help to you. [KnockoutJS & Pager Example (Not completed)](https://github.com/iamshanedoyle/KnockoutJSCarTax)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Look at my collection of bindings

Checkout the [GitHub](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings) and [example](http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/130/) links

Look at the tabs binding

```
<div data-bind="tabs: tabs, tabsOptions: { selectedTab: selectedTabModel, enable: tabsEnabled }"></div>
```