# Can 2 pages use the same viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a huge problem. My application is containing about 10 forms and every form contains a lot of input boxes. The view model is aleady huge, but this is not what makes me warry. In few forms I need to open a popup window and make some calculations based on the values entered in the form (using the ko komputed). I really would like to avoid the creation of a new viemodel(if possible) for every form and popup window.

Is there a way to have a new window using the same viemodel? If so, will the computed fields be working?

Sorry for the messy question, but I really can not figure it out.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293761/knockoutjs-multiple-viewmodels-in-a-single-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use html popups (such as a modal dialog in jQuery UI), rather than actual popups?

I would also suggest that you should have a single view model per form, unless they really do have all the same data bindings.

Comment: Sounds good! I will try it, but I'm not sure, if I can add 2 rows in the modal dialog. Anyways. It seems as the best option I have! Thanks for your help!