# Knockout Passing Value between two view models

Tags: knockout.js

How to pass the visible property of an element, in two different view model.Suppose in 1 view model i have visible is false, in another view model in click function i want to make that visible true. Can It be possible Using Knockout.

```
   ViewModel1 = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dataItem = ko.observable(false);
      };
```

Viewmodel 2

```
   ViewModel2 = function() {
      var self = this;

      // Click Function
      this.showItem= function(){
          ViewModel1.dataItem = ko.observable(true);
      };
    };
```

Comment: take a look at the answers on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293761/knockoutjs-multiple-viewmodels-in-a-single-view

Comment: I would suggest adding some code to illustrate what you are trying to do otherwise you risk having your question closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Tanner, In the reference link solution is not suitable for me.Is there any other solution for this? Thanks for the suggestion, i will update my question with some code.

Comment: in ViewModel2 you're calling this.ViewModel1, but surely that is attempting to call a variable called ViewModel1 IN viewmodel2?

Comment: Sorry @Alexander Troup, I just edit that one.Still I am not getting the output.

Comment: when you update a variable, you don't create a new observable, you just update the old one, so instead of ViewModel1.dataItem = ko.observable(true), you would just do ViewModel1.dataItem(true);

Comment: It's worth going through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: I tried with your suggesation @Alexander, But it is throwing error. It  will not able find the the second view model.

Answer (score 1):

You should try an excellent [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox). It is designed to facilitate decoupled communication between separate view models.

In your case you can use it like:

**Note:** *syncWith* used for bidirectional communication, if you want unidirectional communication then you should try *subscribeTo* with *publishOn* methods.

*Viewmodel 1*

```
ViewModel1 = function() {
               var self = this;
               this.dataItem = ko.observable(false).syncWith("visible", true); 
             };
```

*Viewmodel 2*

```
ViewModel2 = function() {
               var self = this;

               self.dataItem = ko.observable().syncWith("visible", true); 

               // Click Function
               this.showItem= function(){
                    self.dataItem = ko.observable(true);
               };
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Click Function
this.showItem= function(){
    ViewModel1.dataItem(true);
};
```