# Knockout.js - Encapsulate View Models and hiding them from outside

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm following the approach suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294752/1081396) to deal with multiple viewModels and use them in different parts of my page.

Some viewmodels will be used in multiple parts of the page and different elements so I prefer not to use [the second suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572094/1081396) that recommends applying viewmodels to certain DOM elements.

So I have something like this:

```
window.masterVM = {
    vmA : new VmA(),
    vmB : new VmB(),
    vmC : new VmC(),
}

ko.applyBindings(masterVM, $(':root').get(0));
```

Now, on my HTML I do these kind of things:

```
<div data-bind="click: masterVM.vmA.demo">Click</div>
<div data-bind="click: masterVM.vmC.demo">Click</div>
```

This makes it accessible in the window object for anyone who want to execute those methods by just doing: `window.masterVM.vmC.demo()`.

Is there any way to hide this an encapsulate it in a way that it is not accessible from the outside?

Comment: Drop me a word if you're looking for something else than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you can simply pass an anonymous object.

For example:

```js
var VmA = function () { this.demo = _ => console.log('VmA'); }
var VmB = function () { this.demo = _ => console.log('VmB'); }
var VmC = function () { this.demo = _ => console.log('VmC'); }

ko.applyBindings({
    vmA : new VmA(),
    vmB : new VmB(),
    vmC : new VmC(),
}, $(':root').get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="click: vmA.demo">ClickA</div>
<div data-bind="click: vmC.demo">ClickC</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The object `masterVM` refers to *is* your viewmodel. In the context of a binding, you will always have access to the root viewmodel through the `$root` binding context.

Your bindings could then be:

```
<div data-bind="click: $root.vmA.demo">Click</div>
<div data-bind="click: $root.vmC.demo">Click</div>
```

Then you could just get rid of the use of the global variables.