# knockout: How to catch the event when all bindings done on the page?

Tags: knockout.js

I saw here similar questions discussing the end of specific element bindings, usually `aferRender` is proposed to use, but what about whole page bindings done event? Is there any? I need to run some jQuery code which just does not work in parallel with bindings.

Answer (score 1):

`ko.applyBindings()` is a blocking call.

Why not simply execute your jQuery code after you execute `ko.applyBindings()`?

Comment: Technically It might be a way out, but in my case it's a separate file (separate partial view in mvc terms) where jQuery code suppose to be located with its own separate logic, while ko.applyBindings() is in the other main page, and I would not like them to be a loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: @YMC: Putting javascript in a view is an anti-pattern.http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/10/31/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code.aspx

Comment: I read the article but honestly I did not get why it is anti-pattern to put javascript code right into the page. As I understand it just says that if you have a bunch of javascript code it's more maintainable to organize it into nested closures, I don have clunky code, it's few lines of code.

Comment: @YMC: Did you see this snippet? *Most people (including myself) start out writing JavaScript code by adding function after function into a .js or HTML file. While there’s certainly nothing wrong with that approach since it gets the job done, it can quickly get out of control when working with a lot of code. When lumping functions into a file, finding code can be difficult, refactoring code is a huge chore (unless you have a nice tool like Resharper 6.0), variable scope can become an issue, and performing maintenance on the code can be a nightmare especially if you didn’t originally write it.*

Comment: @YMC: Your code may not be clunky right now, but it's likely that it will be extended later, perhaps by developers other than yourself, and that's when it can become a maintenance nightmare. // Also, javascript code is much more *readable* when it exists by itself in its own file.

Comment: Ok, but does it change anything in the initial question? Let say I'll have separate javascript class to handle the local partial view logic which I do not wanna mix with main page logic, and I want main page where applyBindings() is located does not know who and when to run. How can I catch post-binding even in the case?

Comment: @YMC: At some level, the components need to know about each other. Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7342861/109941

Comment: It's not separate ajax call in my case, single data model and one-time applyBindings() call. I just hoped there is some special event provided by KO to bind to, informing about bindings done like $(document).ready in jQuery, if is not, I have to restructure my code anyway