# Second applyBindings doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, data-binding, input, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KnockoutJS: ko.applyBindings to partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/knockoutjs-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view)

I use knockout with jQuery. As result of the basic example below, the text `"Planet Earth"` is displayed fine (so knockout added properly and works!), but  `"Planet2 Earth2"` is not displayed. Also, `alert('alert2');` is fired, but `alert('alert3');` is not.
Could anybody explain me why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("alert1");

        var viewModel = {
            firstName: ko.observable("Planet"),
            lastName: ko.observable("Earth")
        };
        viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
        });

        alert("alert2");
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        alert('alert3');


        var viewModel2 = {
            firstName2: ko.observable("Planet2"),
            lastName2: ko.observable("Earth2")
        };
        viewModel2.fullName2 = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return viewModel2.firstName2() + " " + viewModel2.lastName2();
        });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel2);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid red;">   
<p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
<p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid green;">   
<p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName2' /></p> 
<p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName2' /></p> 
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName2'> </span>!</h2>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/knockoutjs-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view) may help?

Comment: Exactly! I'll post the changes as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for asking a question, and sharing your answer! I'll mark it as a duplicate as well, making it even more convenient for others to find the more detailed version easily if they land here.

Comment: No problem at all!:)
And thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you have to modify 4 lines:

to apply `id`s:

```
<div id="one" style="border:1px solid red;">
```

and

```
<div id="two" style="border:1px solid green;">
```

and
use the second parameter for applyBindings:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById("one"));
```

and

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel2,document.getElementById("two"));
```