# Why is the second alert still displaying the first view model (vm1)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the below code and I'm confused why is the second alert displaying the first view model (vm1) instead of the second one (vm2)?

```
<div id="main">
    <div data-bind="testBinding: vm1"></div>
    <div data-bind="testBinding: vm2"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function vm1() {
        this.firstName = "test first name"
    }

    function vm2() {
        this.lastName = 'test last name';
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.testBinding = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, 
              bindingContext) {

              alert(JSON.stringify(bindingContext.$data))
        },
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new vm1(), document.getElementById('main'));
</script>
```

Comment: Because you create the viewmodel from vm1 `new vm1()` when applying the bindings.

Comment: @M.Ihsan Shouldn't that not matter because I'm looking for all the bindings inside the main div right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990244/whats-the-applybindings-second-parameter-used-for

Comment: Exactly, you're looking at all the bindings inside the main div. But you didn't bind vm2, which is why you can't see it there. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing the first ViewModel (vm1) only because when you apply the binding, you pass viewmodel of the vm1.

```
ko.applyBindings(new vm1(), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Also, `bindingContext` parameter from `ko.bindingHandlers` will get you the viewModel that you pass to the `ko.applyBinidngs`. Since you pass the first viewmodel during the binding, you'll only get that information.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

If you want to get both v1 and v2 from the `ko.bindingHandlers`, you can create another viewmodel and create 2 properties for each of them.

```
function vm1() {
    this.firstName = "test first name"
}

function vm2() {
    this.lastName = 'test last name';
}

function viewModel() {
  this.vm1 = new vm1();
  this.vm2 = new vm2();
}

ko.bindingHandlers.testBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, 
          bindingContext) {

          alert(JSON.stringify(bindingContext.$data))
    },
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Then you'll get this result on the alert box

`{"vm1":{"firstName":"test first name"},"vm2":{"lastName":"test last name"}}`

Comment: Thanks your answer makes sense! Is there a way to create a child context using template binding?