# How to inject jQuery Template with Knockout bindings

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

At first, I have a Button `addTemplate` that will add html to my body via Knockout and jQuery:

```
<button data-bind="click: addTemplate">Add Template</button>

<script type="text/html" id="MyTemplate">
    <div id="container">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.doAlert">Do Alert</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

The added Template has some knockout Bindings, too. They should activate an Alert in my ViewModel:

```
function MyViewModel()
{
    self = this;

    self.addTemplate = function () {
        $($("#MyTemplate").html()).appendTo("body");
    }

    self.doAlert = function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    } 
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

When I click on the Link in my added Template, the `doAlert` function does nothing.
I do not want to use string-chained HTML Templates in my ViewModel.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgu8C/5/

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS: ko.applyBindings to partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/knockoutjs-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view)

Comment: That answer gives you what you need to apply bindings to a specific portion of your page that wasn't available at first run

Answer (score 1):

You should apply binding to newly added element.

```
var newElement = $($("#MyTemplate").html()).appendTo("body");
ko.applyBindings(self, newElement);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4Qm7/)

Answer (score 0):

Without a broader understanding of the context of the problem which you are trying to solve I could be barking up the wrong tree.  However, I suspect you are tackling the problem in the wrong way.  You should never need to repeatedly add the template to the DOM.  Using [Knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) as they were intended will do this for you.  May I suggest the following model...

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.add = function () {
        self.items.push({});
    };

    self.doAlert = function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    } 
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

... accompanied with the following markup ...

```
<button data-bind="click: add">Add Template</button>
<!-- ko template: { name: 'myTemplate', foreach: items } -->
<!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.doAlert">Do Alert</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

I should also point out that I've replaced the id of the **container** with a CSS class as this makes much more sense.