# How do I deal with bindings with master and view pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I need a binding done on my master page, but I also have bindings on my views.

Knockout does not allow for multiple bindings on a view. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711456/935037

Has anyone had a similar problem where they had to bind something that will show everywhere, but still use bindings on local (non master) pages?

**EDIT 1:**

Solution is here: [How do I rebind the knockout viewmodel when the page is loaded in as a partial via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243272/how-do-i-rebind-the-knockout-viewmodel-when-the-page-is-loaded-in-as-a-partial-v/21243578#21243578)

Comment: knockout does not allow multiple binding _on the same element_. If you have another view, you have another element(s). or not ?

Comment: This answer might be suitable for your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243272/how-do-i-rebind-the-knockout-viewmodel-when-the-page-is-loaded-in-as-a-partial-v/21243578#21243578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here: How do I rebind the knockout viewmodel when the page is loaded in as a partial via ajax?