# knockout js jquery Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Hi I am trying to load  knockout js html pages dynamically from jQuery Load but getting

**You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.**

How do I load knockout js pages with jqyuery load.

What I am trying is to create a navigation framework by loading url page (Views/home.html or Views/login.html)into  when ever user click on link.

So I can't load all knocokout viewmodel on fist load

I am trying to create Navigation model to load/refresh only body of the page not the full page.

For example

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="Views/home.html" class="active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Views/login.html">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Views/Contactus.html">Contactus</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

<div id="body"></div>
```

if Home click

```
  $("#body").load("Views/home.html");
```

if Login click

```
  $("#body").load("Views/login.html");
```

**Home.html**

```
 var homeViewModel= function() {
            this.firstName = ko.observable();
            this.lastName = ko.observable();          
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new homeViewModel());
```

**Login.html**

```
  var loginViewModel= function () {
        this.username = ko.observable("test");
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new loginViewModel())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS: ko.applyBindings to partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/knockoutjs-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view) - you can pass in the element as the second parameter

Comment: It's not the duplicate.

Comment: What I am trying is to create a navigation model -- loading <div id="body"></div> when ever user click on link. So I can't load all knocokout viewmodel on fist load

Comment: read the second part of what I commented - you need to pass a second parameter to ko.applyBindings, just like they talk about in that question, that applies the bindings only to that element and not to the root.

Comment: Hi PW Kad , I have seen this and tried but the problem is for me div id is body always, can't change

Comment: Then name the id or class dynamically or use a custom binding

Comment: I'm not totally convinced that `jQuery.load()` is necessarily the solution to your problem, looking at what you are trying to achieve here could easily be done with http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html.  I'm happy to supply an example with code if this fits your requirements.

Comment: Hi, I am using jquery.load() for common navigation to load pages, irrespective of page uses knocout js or not. to be more clear , my porject has couple of pages has knocout js and most of pages without knockout js. So I want to load page with jquery.load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached and removed node  but the dependency is always name of viewmodel must be viewModel

```
  ko.cleanNode($("#body")[0]);
                $("#body").load(url, function() {
                    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), $("#body")[0]);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Pager.js](http://pagerjs.com), which extends knockout.js for page history and partial loading.

Load all your javascript in your main page.
Keep the partials (Views/home.html, Views/login.html) containing only html with binding declarations.
You don't need to explicitly call applyBindings when switching partial, Pager.js does that for you (with proper cleanup for all bindings on previous partial).