# How to apply knockout binding in jquery popup dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, popup

I have simple partial view in cshtml with simple view model, like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="@WebSite.Models.DialogTemplates.NewUser">
  <div id="change-state">
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("");
        this.fullName = ko.computed(function() 
        {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
        }, this);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
```

I show this partial view like popup dialog but I do not figure out how to call applyBindings. If I call this after define model, than applyBindings is call before create dialog and not work. I try this too. [Can you call ko.applyBindings to bind a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342814/can-you-call-ko-applybindings-to-bind-a-partial-view)

```
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById("change-state"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is fiddle demostrating possible solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/LhRuC/

You can create the dialog with { autoOpen: false } and show it when needed.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
  <div id="change-state">
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="popup">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl' }"></div>
</div>

<button id="show">Show</button>
```

JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("test");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("test");
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() { 
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), $("#popup").get(0));

$("#popup").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false 
});

$("#show").click(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog("open");
});
```

Not sure I completely got the problem you faced.
If this won't work for you, provide more details in comments.

Comment: +1 no matter what its been useful help to me . god bless